# PHP Flush All Levels of Output Buffering

Tags: php, output-buffering

I'm trying to implement a simple Http Response class that implements Http Streaming (or Chunked-Encoding).  For this to be possible, I need to set `output_buffering = Off` in the php.ini, and flush the output at certain intervals.

PHP does a good job of this automatically - except for the actual flushing mechanism.  I've gotten it to work, but I'm not sure if it's overboard.  I want to know how to flush each level of output buffering at once, without calling a billion functions (I'm not sure which ones are redundant on which environments / in which scenarios).

```
    while (ob_get_level())
    {
        ob_end_flush();
    }

    // print the buffer

    flush();
    ob_flush();
```

Is this overkill?

Comment: Beware that if your php ini configuration for `output_buffering = On` this would cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `ob_flush()` and `ob_end_flush()`. Your while loop is sufficient.

You should also look at: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php

Your need for `flush()` after `ob_end_flush()` depends on how you set this function.