# ob_clean() clean all levels of ob?

Tags: php, ajax, output-buffering

I just had an instance where i was doing a ob_clean(), before echoing my json, for an ajax call.  The problem was, I was 2 levels of ob, at the time, and ob_clean() was only clearing the inner ob.  To clear them both, well, I just did

```
ob_clean();
ob_clean();
```

What is the proper way of cleaning *all* current buffers?

Edit: yes this question is similar, but the other one talks about flushing, i'm talking about cleaning.  There is some things I dont get about end_clean, clean, get_clean, etc, and therefore, the answer is going to be different and nuanced from the other one.

to wit:
given:

```
ob_start();
echo 'before';
ob_start();
echo 'second';
```

:

```
while (ob_get_level()){
        ob_end_clean();
    }
```

works

```
while (ob_get_level()){
        ob_clean();
    }
```

causes an endless loop, eventually timing out.

```
ob_clean();
ob_clean();
ob_clean();
ob_clean();
ob_clean();
```

does not work. ( still echos: 'before' )

```
 ob_get_clean();
 ob_get_clean();
```

works

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_end_clean();
```

works

Comment: there isn't any. it's up to you to keep track of how many ob buffers have been started. this is to prevent "child" code from messing with buffers established by "parent" code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Flush All Levels of Output Buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549347/php-flush-all-levels-of-output-buffering)

Comment: Ok, I need to tell yall:  if you are doing like `ob_start();include 'view.php';$out = ob_get_clean;` and you have an error in your view, it's going to screw up your buffer, and flush all over where you dont want, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply run `ob_get_level()` in a `while` loop, for example:

```
// put this line at the beginning of your script
// to disable auto-buffering through output_buffering ini directive
if (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
ob_start();
ob_start();
ob_start();

$out = '';

while (ob_get_level())
{
    echo ob_get_level()."\n";
    $out .= ob_get_clean();
}

echo $out;
```